# Splitting Linq Query across Multiple Functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have the following Linq Query operation (Simplified version) which is contained in a single function

```
    var emp = from e in context.DB_Employee
              .Skip(0) 
              .Take(10)
          select new Employee
          {
              id = e.Id,
              name = e.Name
              address = context.DB_Address.Where(a => a.Id == e.Id)
                  .Select(a => new Address
                  {
                      houseNumber = a.HouseNumber
                      street = a.Street
                      country = a.Country
                  }).ToArray(),
                  
                  
              benefits = context.DB_Benefits.Where(b => b.Id == e.Id)
                  .Select(b => new EmployeeBenefits
                  {
                      startDate = b.StartDate
                      expiryDate = b.ExpiryDate
                  }).ToArray(),
          }
```

Calling the function will return a result like the below

```
  {
    "Employee": {
        "id ": 1,
        "name ": "John",
        "address": {
            "houseNumber": "20",
            "street": "street_1",
            "country": "country_1"
        },
        "benefits": {
            "startDate": "2020-01-01",
            "expiryDate": "2020-01-01"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to refactor this single function into multiple functions so I have the flexibility to choose the bits to add to the final output. The functions would be layed out something like this

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee()
{
...
AddAddress();
AddBenefits();
...
}
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering when you create a method `AddAddress()` that contains the linq for the `address` ?

Comment: Im just not sure how to split it out into seperate functions

Comment: There is no relationship between your existing query between the Address and Benefits.  One is using e.FPI_ID and the other e.Id.  So separating the two queries gets same results.  Don't you want to link to a common employee?

Comment: Typo. Now edited

Answer (score 1):

The first question would be "Why?" Why do you want to split up the data retrieval across multiple methods and potentially make it conditional? It is certainly possible, but you are taking a fairly efficient query and will be replacing it with several less efficient queries.

Looking at your example, the first thing I see missing are navigation properties for the relationships between Employee, Address, and Benefits. From reading the relationships I would expect to see something like:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
    public virtual ICollection<Benefit> Benefits { get; set; } = new List<Benefit>();
}
```

... then to query...

```
var employees = context.DB_Employee
    .Select(x => new Employee
          {
              id = e.Id,
              name = e.Name
              addresses = e.Addresses
                  .Select(a => new Address
                  {
                      houseNumber = a.HouseNumber
                      street = a.Street
                      country = a.Country
                  }).ToArray(),
              benefits = e.Benefits
                  .Select(b => new EmployeeBenefits
                  {
                      startDate = b.StartDate
                      expiryDate = b.ExpiryDate
                  }).ToArray(),
          })
    .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToArray();
```

Libraries like Automapper can simplify this even further with `ProjectTo` where you configure Automapper with how to translate Entity to ViewModel, and it does the rest as opposed to the various `Select` statements.

```
var employees = context.DB_Employee
    .ProjectTo<Employee>(config)
    .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToArray();
```

... where `config` is the Automapper config for mapping. (not shown, check Automapper documentation for examples)

From there, the question is Why would this need to be split up? We've got an Employee(ViewModel?) which should reflect the type of data the view is expecting. It's generally not a good idea to conditionally populate data in a model otherwise the consumers of that model will have to inspect the model to somehow determine whether it's complete enough for them. (Do I expect Addresses or not? etc.)  If I did want to introduce conditional details then I would look at using separate view models. For example if I wanted to return just employee details vs. employee details /w address & benefits:

```
if (includeDetails)
    return  context.DB_Employee
        .ProjectTo<EmployeeWithDetails>(config)
        .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToArray();
else
    return  context.DB_Employee
        .ProjectTo<EmployeeSummary>(config)
        .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToArray();
```

Where I define different view models (`EmployeeWithDetails` and `EmployeeSummary`) with the appropriate mapping rules, then depending on the conditional logic, populate one or the other. This could be done with `switch`/`case` etc. I would avoid conditionally appending fields to a single model:

```
var employees = context.DB_Employee
    .ProjectTo<Employee>(config)
    .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToArray();

if (includeAddresses)
{
    foreach(var employee in employees)        
        employee.Addresses = context.DB_Addresses
            .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employee.Id)
            .ProjectTo<Address>()
            .ToArray();
}

if (includeBenefits)
{
    foreach(var employee in employees)        
        employee.Benefits = context.DB_Benefits
            .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employee.Id)
            .ProjectTo<Benefit>()
            .ToArray();
}
```

The problems with this approach are that consumers expecting "Employee" models may or may not get addresses and/or benefits. There is also the issue of extra querying to get the conditional data: Like other examples such as:

```
select new Employee
{
    id = e.Id,
    name = e.Name
    address = _addressService.GetAddress(context),    
    benefits = _benefitsService.GetBenefits(context)
}
```

The issue here is that you are querying the DB for the Address and again for the Benefit for each and every employee you load, rather than loading them as part of the Employee load.

So to fetch 10 employees where you also want address and benefits, you're executing 21 queries instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Refactored Code: Address and EmployeeBenefit implemented from other function and called both the function in employee LINQ query

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee()
{  
    var emp = context.DB_Employee.AsEnumerable().Skip(0).Take(10)
                select (e=>new Employee
                      {
                          id = e.Id,
                          name = e.Name,
                          address = GetAddress(context),
                          EmployeeBenefits=GetEmployeeBenefits(context)
                }).ToList();
}
```

`Address` Function

```
public List<Address> GetAddress(DBContext _context)
{
     return _contextDB_Address.Where(a => a.Id == e.Id)
                  .Select(a => new Address
                  {
                      houseNumber = a.HouseNumber
                      street = a.Street
                      country = a.Country
                  }).ToList(),
}
```

`EmployeeBenefits` function

```
public List<EmployeeBenefits> GetEmployeeBenefits(DBContext _context)
{
     return _context.DB_Benefits.Where(b => b.Id == e.Id)
                  .Select(b => new EmployeeBenefits
                  {
                      startDate = b.StartDate
                      expiryDate = b.ExpiryDate
                  }).ToList(),
}
```

Comment: Im getting error: 'The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of '<the_class_name>' through the instance method 'GetAddress'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance. When i chnage the GetAddress function to static i get error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first"

Comment: I had to add "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" to the connection string for it to work